Phonepe PG Integration:Error with checksum,thus geeting 401 error
I am working on integrating phonepe pg in which daily donation will be recived bt the ngo.so I have been able to create a subscription id through their api and after that on step 2 I have to submit a auth request which will give me a response url.In header parameter it takes three mandatory field of Content type,X-verify:checksum and X-callback url ,as per their documentation 401 error means incorrect checksum for which calculation has to be   SHA256(base64 encoded payload + “/v3/recurring/auth/init” + salt key) + ### + salt index,and my method is working for their other api but in this  it's not.
  <?php

// Define your salt key and salt index
$salt_key = '099eb0cd-02cf-4e2a-8aca-3e6c6aff0399';
$salt_index= "1"; // Assuming it's a constant value
$merchantUserId = "USA".rand("1444","8999");
$authRequestId = "TXT".rand("1200","6000");

// Define your request payload
$requestPayload = array(
    "merchantId" => "PGTESTPAYUAT",
    "merchantUserId" => "USA5345",
    "subscriptionId" => "OMS2404251442179166930186D",
    "authRequestId" => "TXI2092",
    "amount" => 39900,
    "paymentInstrument" => array(
        "type" => "UPI_QR",
    )
);

// Convert the payload to JSON
$jsonPayload = json_encode($requestPayload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Base64 encode the JSON payload
$base64_payload = base64_encode($jsonPayload);

// Format the encoded string for better readability
$formattedEncodedString = chunk_split($base64_payload, 64, "\n");
$x_verify = hash('sha256', $formattedEncodedString. "/v3/recurring/auth/init" . $salt_key) . '###' . $salt_index;


// Define your headers
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept: application/json", // Specify that we accept JSON content
    'X-Verify: da215e27adf9e82f432a2bd5145af4a0618b87f99671541b07c59dca7738cfee###1',
    "X-CALLBACK-URL: http://localhost/sub/yp.php"
);


// Define the API endpoint
$apiEndpoint = "https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/v3/recurring/auth/init";

// Initialize cURL session
$curl = curl_init();

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $apiEndpoint,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array("request" => $base64_payload )),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
));

// Execute the cURL request
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Check for errors
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
    
// Close cURL session
curl_close($curl);

// Print API response
echo $response;


?>

above code
response : {
    "success": false,
    "code": "401"
}

I have tried to change base64encode as their dev team told me it was wrong but even then it's not working  .Please suggest something ?
documentation link: https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/submit-auth-request/
